# How to package code on Pypi (__init__.py) with class within subfolders

Tags: python, pypi

if my directory structure is like this:

```
| - myproject
| | - \\
| | - __init__.py
| | - lib
| | | - __init__.py
| | ` - objects
| | | - class.py
| | ` - __init__.py
| | - module.py
```

What do I put in my `__init__.py` file? I tried:

```
'from lib.object import class'
```

When I do a 'python setup.py sdist' and check the MANIFEST file, the class is not included. I only see `module.py` along with `setup.cfg` and `setup.py`

Comment: What's the contents of your `setup.py` file?

Comment: Any particular section you would like me to paste? It's quite big to paste all...

Comment: Is the module really called `class.py`? That's a bad name — `class` is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) in Python and cannot be used for names.

Comment: No, I just used it for the sake of this example to illustrate what is a module vs. class. It's actually named something else.

Comment: Did you follow https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't explain how I can import from subdirectory within subdirectory. My path is /myproject/lib/objects/class.py. I have 'from lib.object import class'. I've tried I have 'from lib.object.class import ClassName' but no luck.